# Spring/Hibernate: Data written to DB outside TX

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

Versions:
Spring 4.3.6
Hibernate: 5.2.6

```
tx = session.beginTransaction();
Customer cust = session.get(Customer.class, "some id");
tx.commit();

cust.setName('Some Name');
// Not written to DB

tx = session.beginTransaction();
tx.commit();
// Customer is updated in DB
```

Now, after last begin/commit, customer has been updated. Why?

Comment: It may be possible if you are using it with spring then there may be another transaction over method or calling method like @Transaction annotation.

Comment: Well, actually I'm using Struts2 actions and OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter. So the only Transactional Spring bean is a DAO, which is injected using @Autowired into a Struts2 Action. When retrieving an entity from DAO, and changing a property to that entity from the action class, the change is actually written to DB. I'm not getting this!

Comment: Most probably Hibernate will commit the transaction for you as you did do any rollback, even if you lost the reference to that transaction

Comment: So what is best practice for Struts actions and DAO beans? Should I make the action transactional? I could add a merge method to the DAO and call that when I have updated an entity.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want this to happen, you need to set autocommit to false either when configuring the DataSource, or in spring properties.